# DistributeDefinitions and synchronization in Mathematica 10

Tags: parallelization

The command `DistributeDefinitions[z]` installs all current definitions for `z` on the local kernels. A simple example: we assign the value 1 to `z` in the mainkernel, distribute the definitions of `z` and inspect the values of `z` in the subkernels. All are 1.

```
z=1;
DistributeDefinitions[z];
{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
(* {1,{1,1,1,1}} *)
```

The function DistributeDefinitions does not establish a synchronization between the local kernels and the main kernel. Therefore, when change `z` to 2 in the main kernel, in the subkernels the value of z is still 1:

```
z=2;
{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
(* {2,{1,1,1,1}} *)
```

Anyway, that was the result in Mathematica 8 and Mathematica 9. But Mathematica 10.4 does at least some synchronization. There we obtain

```
z=1;
DistributeDefinitions[z];
{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
z=2;
{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
(* {1,{1,1,1,1}} *)
(* {2,{2,2,2,2}} *)
```

Does someone know what exactly has changed in DistributeDefinitions? The documentation does not help me, but I might have overlooked a release note.

**Edit**

After some further playing, I found the following buggish behaviour:

```
z=4;
DistributeDefinitions[z]
(* {z} *)

{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
(* {4,{4,4,4,4}} *)

ParallelEvaluate[ValueQ[z]]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)

ParallelEvaluate[Clear[z]]
(*  {Null,Null,Null,Null} *)

ParallelEvaluate[ValueQ[z]]
(* {False,False,False,False} *)

{z, ParallelEvaluate[z]}
(* {4,{4,4,4,4}} *)

{z, ParallelEvaluate[1+z^2]}
(* {4,{17,17,17,17}} *)

ParallelEvaluate[ValueQ[z]]
(* {False,False,False,False} *)
```

We can do numerical computations with variables that do not have a value!

Comment: I didn't know about this change ... `DistributeDefinitions` does register distributed symbols, see ``Parallel`Developer`$DistributedDefinitions``.  Perhaps this is a good starting point for researching what happens.

Comment: @FredSimons Thanks for the UPDATE. It is strange that there are no standard "Updated in 2016 (10.4)" footnotes both at the Documentation page for `ParallelEvaluate` and `DistributedContexts`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to Wolfram Technical Support,  I am now able to answer my own question and explain the results I showed in the Edit.

My question was: what exactly has changed in `DistributeDefinitions`? The answer is simple: nothing. **What I observed is due to a undocumented change in `ParallelEvaluate`. Since version 10.4, it  has an option `DistributedContexts` with default value `$DistributedContexts`. So when we call `ParallelEvaluate`, the first thing that happens now is that the required definitions are automatically distributed to the subkernels.**  In version 10.3 and earlier, `ParallelEvaluate` did not automatically distribute definitions.

That explains why the command

```
z=1; DistributeDefinitions[z];
z=2; ParallelEvaluate[z]
```

now returns `{2,2,2,2}` instead of `{1,1,1,1}` as in earlier versions.

Then, in the Edit, I reported some buggish results. It already follows from the comment of Alexey Popkov that these results have nothing to do with the the new behaviour of `ParallelEvaluate`. Now I feel both amused and ashamed about this Edit, for it it not bug at all. It is a simple consequence of something that I have seen already hundreds of times.

This is essentially what I did in the Edit.

```
z=4; DistributeDefinitions[z];
ParallelEvaluate[z]
(* {4,4,4,4} *)
ParallelEvaluate[Clear[z]];
ParallelEvaluate[z]
(* {4,4,4,4} *)
```

The second result highly surprised me, since I cleared the values of `z` in the subkernels.

Before Mathematica 10.4, the explanation is simple. The result of the second `ParallelEvaluate[z]` is the list `{z,z,z,z}`. In the main kernel, `z` still has the value 4, so this list evaluates further to the output `{4,4,4,4}`.

In Mathematica 10.4, we might think that the result of the second `ParallelEvaluate[z]` is due to another distribution of the definition of `z`. That this has not happened can be seen as follows:

```
ParallelEvaluate[ValueQ[z]]
(* {False,False,False,False} *)
```

Another distribution is only done when the value of `z` has changed, like here:

```
z=1;ParallelEvaluate[ValueQ[z]]
(* {True,True,True,True} *)
```

Therefore, also in Mathematica 10.4, the result `{4,4,4,4}` is due to a further evaluation of `{z,z,z,z}`.

Comment: I still do not get why we get ParallelEvaluate[z] (* {4,4,4,4} *) after the Clear[z] and still ValueQ[z] is false. Which mechanism makes the 4 know to ParallelEvaluate[z] after ParallelEvaluate[Clear[z]] if not DistributeDefinitions?

Comment: @Eisbär. After ParallelEvaluate[Clear[z]], the value of z in the subkernels is cleared, but in the main kernel the valueof z is still 4. Therefore, ParallelEvaluate[z] (which now does not redistribute the definition of z to the subkernels) returns the list {z,z,z,z} in the main kernel. But in the main kernel this list further evaluates to {4,4,4,4}.

Comment: Thats a tricky one, as it is not actually returning the true value as given by the parallel kernel but an interpretation of that by the master kernel. I have to rember that one. Thank you for elaborating.