# How are function definitions distributed to parallel kernels?

Tags: parallelization

For example, I define a function f.

```
f[x_] := x^2;
```

And when I execute

```
ParallelTable[f[i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

I get

```
{1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100}
```

as expected. (my function definition has propagated to the parallel kernels)

Now, if I do

```
Unprotect[Print];
Print = Null;
```

and

```
ParallelDo[Print[i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

I expect nothing to be printed out because I have changed the Print function. But instead, I get the printout.

```
1
3
5
7
9
10
2
4
6
8
```

Why did my function definition propagate to the parallel kernels in the first example, but not in the second example?

Comment: Seemingly minor but important point: Definitions are *shared among subkernels*.  They are "distritbuted" (copied to) the subkernels directly from the main kernel.  I changed the title to avoid confusion with `SetSharedVariable`/`SetSharedFunction`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Print` didn't get distributed because it was in the `` System` `` context.  By default only `` Global` `` (or rather `$Context`) symbols are distributed.

Definitions are sent to subkernels using [`DistributeDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributeDefinitions.html).  Both this function and those that call is have the [`DistributedContexts`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DistributedContexts.html) options which *usually* defaults to `$DistributedContexts`, which in turn is set to

```
$DistributedContexts := $Context
```

You can set these to choose which contexts will get distributed.

Auto-distributing everything by default would lead to breakage soon due to many different reasons (loading a package often does more than issue definitions, some contexts hold mutable state such as caches, etc.)

Related:

- [Contexts and parallelization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128285/12)

---

That said, attempting to distribute (automatically or manually) any `` System` `` symbols is a patently bad idea that could very easily lead to breakage.  While I haven't tried to find out if it is so, I wouldn't be surprised if the system protected itself against this even beyond the fact that these symbols are `Protected` on the subkernels as well, which alone would break distribution anyway.