# Should I use `ParallelNeeds` or `DistributedContexts`?

Tags: parallelization

According to Mathematica documentation, `ParallelNeeds` can load packages for all kernels, while parallelized functions like `ParallelTable` have the option `DistributedContexts` which allows you to distribute the definitions of a package over all kernels. Am I right that `ParallelNeeds` and `DistributedContexts` can be used to achieve the same results? If so, how should I choose between the two?

Comment: [This answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128287/9490) may shed some light on the matter.  If it does answer your question you should make an answer here, rather than close this as a duplicate